# jQuery Show DIV and Remove Button

Tags: jquery

Playing with jQuery,

I wanted to remove the button after displaying div (#div-wordpress)

I thought I understood the trick but no ... It didn't work I think I forgot something.

[image]

if someone can show me the most modern and easy way to do it

clic = **Show** div and **Remove** the button

My code

```
/* Show/Hide my div*/   
jQuery(document).on('click','#my-button',function() {
      jQuery('#div-wordpress').slideToggle('230','swing','hide');
      jQuery(this).remove();//supposed to be #my-button ?
     });
```

Comment: This isn't a WordPress query, you should ask this on stackoverflow instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
/* Show/Hide my div*/   
jQuery(document).on('click','.my-button',function() {
  //jQuery('.div-wordpress').slideToggle('230','swing','hide');
  this.remove();//supposed to be #my-button ?
});
```

Note that I have swapped ids for classes and just made a small JS update - `this` is the clicked element inside a jQuery event - not `jQuery(this)`

Here is a CodePen: https://codepen.io/qstudio/pen/PoGdLgX

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I want to keep .div-wordpress and only delete .my-button

Comment: jQuery('.div-wordpress').slideToggle('230','swing','hide'); - your original code "toggled" the div - this would hide it, if it was shown..

Comment: Updated to only hide the click button element

Comment: Thank you Q Studio I learned how to do it